# The envelope of a set of translated and rotated ellipses

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, geometry, envelope

I achieve a dynamic graphics by using `Manipulate` as follows:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  RotationMatrix[β].{a + c Cos[Θ], b + d Sin[Θ]}, {Θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}],
 {{a, 1}, 0, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {b, 0, 6, 1}, {c, 1, 5, 1}, 
 {d, 2, 6, 1}, {β, 0, π, 1}]
```

> [image: an ellipse]

To see the dynamic region, I do the following operation:

```
Table[
 ParametricPlot[
  RotationMatrix[β].{a + c Cos[Θ], b + d Sin[Θ]}, {Θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}],
 {a, 0, 5, 1},
 {b, 0, 6, 1}, {c, 1, 5, 1}, 
 {d, 2, 6, 1}, {β, 0, π, 1}]// Flatten // Show
```

> [image: envelope]

In addition, I noticed that

```
ParametricPlot[
 r^2 { Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 3 π/2}, {r, 1, 2}]
```

can give a region of a dynamic graphic. However, it *cannot* work *when the parameters exceed 2*

> [image]

---

#### Question

Is it possible to achieve the ***envelope line*** of a set of dynamic graphs ?
It is my first time to think out this question and I have no idea.

> [image]

Comment: You have an envelope of parametrically-defined curves; as noted [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Envelope.html) or [here](http://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/enveloppe/enveloppe.shtml) (*en Français*, sorry), you can derive the envelope's parametric equations by eliminating the free parameter from the parametric equations and the determinant of its partial derivatives.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Thanks for your reference:-)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  The problem, as I see it, is that the free parameters are discrete.  If they were continuous, the bounding curve would be simply a circle.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, true; that makes computing an explicit representation of the envelope harder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem can be simplified substantially by noting that only the largest ellipses contribute to the boundary of the second figure in the question.  So, for instance,

```
Table[ParametricPlot[RotationMatrix[β].{a + 5 Cos[Θ], b + 6 Sin[Θ]}, {Θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}], {a, 0, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 6, 1}, {β, 0, Pi, 1}]
  // Flatten // Show
```

[image]

Furthermore, this plot is seen to be the composite of four objects,

```
Table[ParametricPlot[{a + 5 Cos[Θ], b + 6 Sin[Θ]}, {Θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}], {a, -2.5, 2.5, 1}, {b, -2.5, 2.5, 1}]
  // Flatten // Show
```

[image]

each one displaced by the average values of `a` and `b`, `{2.5, 3.0}` in this case, and rotated by the four values of `β`.

**Continuation**

The region corresponding to the previous plot is approximately (exactly in  the limit of continuous `a` and `b`) is

```
r = RegionUnion[Flatten[{
    Table[Ellipsoid[{a, b}, {5, 6}], {a, -2.5, 2.5, 5}, {b, -2.5, 2.5, 5}], 
    Rectangle[{-2.5, -8.5}, {2.5, 8.5}], Rectangle[{-7.5, -2.5}, {7.5, 2.5}]}]];
RegionPlot[r, PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}]
```

[image]

This region then is translated by `{2.5, 3.0}` and rotated by `β`.

```
t = TransformedRegion[r, TranslationTransform[{2.5, 3}]];
s = RegionUnion[Table[TransformedRegion[t, RotationTransform[β]], {β, 0, Pi, 1}]];
```

The boundary of `s` is the desired surface.

```
u = RegionBoundary[s];
RegionPlot[u, PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}]
DeleteCases[%, Line[{_, _}] | Point[__], Infinity]
```

[image]

The last line of code eliminates most spurious points and point-like lines that mysteriously (to me) otherwise appear.

Warning: Trying to plot `s` itself promptly devoured all the memory on my PC.

Comment: This is very elegant. I had been thinking about this problem since the question came out, but I had gotten nowhere. Thanks for putting me out of my misery! (+1)

Answer (score 6):

The general idea is the same as bbgodfrey's so most credits for him, the approach is slightly different, perhaps more automatic.

We start by converting OP's parametric expression to cartesian:

```
eq = #.# &@{Cos[Θ], Sin[Θ]} /. Solve[
     Thread[{x, y} == RotationMatrix[β].{a + c Cos[Θ], b + d Sin[Θ]}],
     {Cos[Θ], Sin[Θ]}
     ][[1]] // Simplify
```

> [image]

```
(regions = Table[
      ImplicitRegion[eq <= 1, {x, y}],
      {a, 0, 5, 1}, {b, 0, 6, 1}, {c, 5, 5, 1}, {d, 6, 6, 1}, {β, 0, π, 1}
 ] // Flatten // N);
 (*only the biggest c and d as noticed by bbdogfrey*)

RegionUnion[regions] // DiscretizeRegion[#, AccuracyGoal -> 3] & // 
   RegionBoundary // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Kuba, elegant solution.  Well done.  Do you understand why using `DiscretizeRegion[#]] & // RegionBoundary ` decreases running time by orders of magnitude, compared to `RegionBoundary // RegionPlot`?

Comment: Shutao Tang, although I cannot speak for Kuba, I would note that `DiscretizeRegion` is new to Mathematica 10.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I don't know, I'm not so much experienced in Regions. :/

Comment: @ShutaoTang Yes, this is V10 solution. You could try to mimic this. Plot filled ellipses, extract polygons, find here a function to merge polygons (it is somewhere, I don't know where). Fold this operation on a list of ellipses and you have a solution. Probably, haven;t tested it and don't have time :/

Comment: @Kuba, Thanks very much sincerely:-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach came from this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110236/is-there-a-numerical-method-built-in-to-calculate-the-boundary-of-a-set-of-graph/110608#110608) and [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey)'s answer. In addition, it is very fast.

```
s = 
  DiscretizeGraphics@
    Graphics[Polygon /@ 
      Table[Table[{a + 5 Cos[theta], b + 6 Sin[theta]}, 
      {theta, 0, 2 Pi, 0.02 Pi}], {a, -2.5, 2.5, 1}, {b, -2.5, 2.5, 1}]]
```

[image]

```
t = TransformedRegion[s, TranslationTransform[{2.5, 3}]];
RegionBoundary@
  RegionUnion[
   Table[TransformedRegion[t, RotationTransform[beta]], {beta, 0, Pi, 1}]]
```

[image]

[image]