# Is there a numerical method/built-in to calculate the boundary of a set of graphs?

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, envelope

Recently, I encounted a geometry problem in my work. For a curve-family that owns the following parametric equation:
$$E(t,\theta)=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_E(t,\theta) \\
y_E(t,\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$

where, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $t\in [0,1]$

Traditionally, I could apply the [*envelope theory*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Envelope.html) to solve the points that located in the boundary.

$$\frac{\partial x_E(t,\theta)}{\partial t}\frac{\partial y_E(t,\theta)}{\partial \theta}-\frac{\partial x_E(t,\theta)}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial y_E(t,\theta)}{\partial t}=0 \qquad (1)$$

So for the fixed $t_i$, the parameter of envelope-point $\theta_i$ could be solved with equation$(1)$

Here is a normal instance that using above theory(denoted envelope-point with $\color{blue} \square$).

[image]

Obvisouly, I can connect $P_{0,1}, P_{1,1}, \dots P_{4,1}$ and $P_{0,2},P_{1,2},\dots P_{4,2}$ in sequence to achieve the boundary/envelope.

However, for the complicated case, there are only some envelope-points(denoted with $\color{blue} \square$) on the boundary/envelope. That is, the *envelope theory* will unapplicable.

[image]

So my question is:

- Is there a **numerical method**/*built-in* to calculate the boundary?(and achieve the coordinates of points that located on the boundary)

---

#### Update

Here are some data

```
coeff = {{{0., -5., 0}, {-5.2203, 0., 1.7945}}, 
 {{-0.4188, -4.9846, 0.1071}, {-5.3218, 0.3923, 2.0267}}, 
 {{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.1765}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 2.3088}}, 
 {{-1.3234, -4.8618, 0.2192}, {-5.5122, 1.1672, 2.6475}}, 
 {{-1.8203, -4.7553, 0.2473}, {-5.6022, 1.5451, 3.0486}}, 
 {{-2.3568, -4.6194, 0.2742}, {-5.6897, 1.9134, 3.5173}}, 
 {{-2.9427, -4.455, 0.3147}, {-5.7755, 2.27, 4.0578}}, 
 {{-3.5912, -4.2632, 0.3857}, {-5.8604, 2.6125, 4.6738}}, 
 {{-4.3197, -4.0451, 0.5068}, {-5.9456, 2.9389, 5.368}}, 
 {{-5.1524, -3.802, 0.7017}, {-6.0327, 3.2472, 6.1428}}, 
 {{-6.1237, -3.5355, 1.}, {-6.1237, 3.5355, 7.}}};

coeff2 = {{{0., -5., 0}, {-5.2203, 0., 1.7945}}, 
 {{-0.4188, -4.9846, 0.3754}, {-5.3218, 0.3923, 1.8307}}, 
 {{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.6792}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 1.8663}}, 
 {{-1.3234, -4.8618, 0.9146}, {-5.5122, 1.1672, 1.9093}}, 
 {{-1.8203, -4.7553, 1.0855}, {-5.6022, 1.5451, 1.9672}}, 
 {{-2.3568, -4.6194, 1.1959}, {-5.6897, 1.9134, 2.047}}, 
 {{-2.9427, -4.455, 1.2502}, {-5.7755, 2.27, 2.1556}}, 
 {{-3.5912, -4.2632, 1.2528}, {-5.8604, 2.6125, 2.2995}}, 
 {{-4.3197, -4.0451, 1.2087}, {-5.9456, 2.9389, 2.4846}}, 
 {{-5.1524, -3.802, 1.1229}, {-6.0327, 3.2472, 2.7164}}, 
 {{-6.1237, -3.5355, 1.}, {-6.1237, 3.5355, 3.}}};
```

which are the coefficient of ellipse. Namely, `{{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}`

$\begin{cases}
 x=a \sin\theta+b \cos\theta +c  \\
 y=d \sin\theta +e \cos\theta +f  \\
\end{cases}$

```
ellipsePoints[{mat1_, mat2_}] :=
 {mat1.{Sin[#], Cos[#], 1},
  mat2.{Sin[#], Cos[#], 1}} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.02 Pi]

points = Flatten[ellipsePoints /@ coeff, 1];
points2 = Flatten[ellipsePoints /@ coeff2, 1];
```

Thanks for RunnyKine's `alphaShapes2D[]` with diferent threshold :`1,3`

```
reg = RegionBoundary@alphaShapes2D[points, 1];
Show[{reg, ListPlot[points, AspectRatio -> Automatic]}, Axes -> True]

reg2 = RegionBoundary@alphaShapes2D[points, 3];
Show[{reg2, ListPlot[point2s, AspectRatio -> Automatic]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Would you ever have a case where your graphs don't form a single connected region? (If so, do you want to find two separate boundaries in that case?)

Comment: @MartinBüttner No, in my case, the graphs always form a single connected regoin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another answer inspired by Rahul's answer that also uses only built-in functions:

```
RegionBoundary @ DiscretizeGraphics @ Graphics[Polygon /@ ellipsePoints /@ coeff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RegionBoundary@
  DiscretizeGraphics@Graphics[Polygon /@ ellipsePoints /@ coeff2]
```

[image]

```
RegionBoundary@
  DiscretizeGraphics@
    Graphics[Polygon /@ 
     Table[
       Table[
         RotationMatrix[m].{2 + 5 Cos[x], 3 + 6 Sin[x]}, 
         {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.02 Pi}], {m, 0, Pi, Pi/20}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, RunnyKine. I would like to know that is it possible to know the **theory/algorithm** behind the built-in `RegionBoundary[]` and `DiscretizeGraphics[]`. THX:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG. I would like to know that myself.

Comment: Maybe the **theory/algorithm** belong to the part of **computational geometry**. However, I have no knowledge about that field.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one way to do it, although it gives you a rasterised result.

```
graph = Table[
    ParametricPlot[
     RotationMatrix[m].{2 + 5 Cos[x], 3 + 6 Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Axes -> None], {m, 0, Pi, 
     Pi/30}] // Flatten // Show

binary = graph // Binarize;
boundary = ImageAdd[
    binary // ColorNegate // DeleteBorderComponents,
    binary
] // EdgeDetect // ColorNegate
```

#### How it works

First, we render the `graph` without the axes (like you already did):

[image]

Then we binarise it and store that in `binary`:

[image]

We want to find the bounary of the outer black region. To do so, we first negate the binary image and remove the outer region with `DeleteBorderComponents` (this is essentially a flood fill with black from the edges):

[image]

If we add these two images together, both the lines of the graph as well as all the regions it encloses will become white, because the lines are white in the original `binary` image and the inner regions are white in the negated image. However, the outer region is black in both so it remains black:

[image]

Now it's trivial to detect the edge. Because `EdgeDetect` shows edges in white on black, we're negating the image again to get black on white:

[image]

I'm looking forward to someone coming up with a solution that gives vectorised output!

Comment: Thanks for your solution:). So I would like to know is it possible to achieve the coordinates of the boundary. Because I need to use these coordinates to do other thing.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Not easily with the rasterised image. You'd need to figure out the scale of the pixels and then you could just check which pixels are black. That's why I'm hoping someone else will come up with a solution in vectorised form. Please edit your question though to clarify exactly what information you need about the boundary.

Answer (score 10):

Since you require the coordinates, a good starting point is to use my `alphaShapes2D` code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o/88769#88769).
Now it's just a matter of the following one-liner:

```
breg = First @ ConnectedMeshComponents @ RegionBoundary @ alphaShapes2D[pts, 0.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here `pts` is as defined in the OP. Since you want the boundary coordinates. you can obtain it through `Meshcoordinates`:

```
MeshCoordinates @ breg
```

Comment: @MartinBüttner this would work:  Last[SortBy[ConnectedMeshComponents[reg], RegionMeasure]]

Comment: Thanks. in my laptop, the **Mathematica 10.0** gives me this [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yTd83.png)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG. That's strange. Is that the result you get from `RegionBoundary @ alphaShapes2D[pts, 0.5]`?

Comment: @RunnyKine Yes, today I ran the code in the other laptop that installed **Mathematica 10.3**, which still gives me this [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjybi.png)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG. OK I just tested in *Mathematica* **10.2** and I get same result as you. It must be a bug that was fixed in **10.4**. Anyways, since you only need the outer boundary, you should still be able to get it with `ConnectedMeshComponents[reg][[1]]`

Comment: @RunnyKine OK, owing to I have no knowledge about **computation geometry**, so thanks for your method and guide:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG. You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: Hi, today I add a group of data that came from my work, however, `RegionBoundary @ alphaShapes2D[pts, 0.5]` cannot find the right boundary. Please see my update.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG. You should try a different parameter for different problem. I used `0.5` because that was what worked. Try to change that number until you get a nice boundary.

Answer (score 9):

Just take the union of the polygons defined by the curves. This uses only built-in functions and doesn't require parameter tuning. I've added `RegionBoundary` to make it look like the other answers.

```
RegionBoundary@
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
  RegionUnion[Polygon /@ ellipsePoints /@ coeff]
```

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, the $\alpha$-shape slightly smooths out the concave corner at the lower left of the figure, while the union doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Today, I discovered an example from *Wolfram Documentation Center* about plotting a parametric region:

```
ParametricPlot[
 r^2 { Sqrt[t] Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {r, 1, 2}]
```

Namely, `ParametricPlot[]` could generate the region of family: $f(\theta,t)$

[image]

For my question, it is a family of ellipses with respect to time variable $t$.

[image]

```
{δxp, δyp, δzp} = {0, 0, 77.5};
{δxw, δyw, δzw} = {-13.123, 3.631, 42.5};
zOmega = 6;
R = 5;

ParametricPlot[
 {R Cos[θC] Cos[θ] + R Sin[θC]/Cos[θA] Sin[θ] + 
  Sin[θC]/Cos[θA] (yM - δyp) + 
  Tan[θA] Sin[θC] (zOmega + δzw - δzp) + 
  Cos[θC] (xM - δxp) + δxp - δxw,

 -R Sin[θC] Cos[θ] + R Cos[θC]/Cos[θA] Sin[θ] + 
  Cos[θC]/Cos[θA] (yM - δyp) + 
  Tan[θA] Cos[θC] (zOmega + δzw - δzp) - 
  Sin[θC] (xM - δxp) + δyp - δyw}, 
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

---

**Case 1**

```
{xM, yM, zM, θA, θC} = 
{13.123 + 2.9665 t, -13.5318 - 9.5375 t, 65.0342 + 6.201 t, 
 -0.2915 - 0.6638 t, -3.1416 + 0.7854 t};
```

[image]

**Case 2**

```
{xM, yM, zM, θA, θC} = 
{13.123 +0.1381 t,-13.5318-5.455 t,65.0342 +5.6236 t,
 -0.2915-0.6638 t,-3.1416+0.7854 t}
```

[image]

**Case 3**

```
{xM, yM, zM, θA, θC} = 
{13.123 -5.5188 t,-13.5318-8.721 t,65.0342 +10.2424 t,
 -0.2915-0.6638 t,-3.1416+0.7854 t}
```

[image]

**Case 4**

```
{xM, yM, zM, θA, θC} = 
{13.123 +4.3807 t,-13.5318-7.9045 t,65.0342 +9.0877 t,
 -0.2915-0.6638 t,-3.1416+0.7854 t}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It doesn't seem easy to extract the boundary from these curves though.

Comment: @RunnyKine Yes, extracting the boundary is hard. Now my thought is converting the first ellipse($t=0$) to a polygon, then using the `RegionUnion[]` operation.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a nice approach.

Comment: @RunnyKinen By far, I think your second approach `RegionBoundary @ DiscretizeGraphics @ Graphics[Polygon /@ ellipsePoints /@ coeff]` is the fastest method, just needing `0.2~0.6 s ` to calculate the boundary of $11$ discretized ellispses. In addition, `ParametricPlot[]` just samples a set of ellipse to achive the region.

Comment: Yes, that approach is quite fast.