# Regression /Bug in DelaunayMesh from 10.3.1 to 10.4

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, backslide

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and persists through 11.1**

---

In answering [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110236/is-there-a-numerical-method-built-in-to-calculate-the-boundary-of-a-set-of-graph), I realized the OP and I were obtaining different results from the [`alphaShapes2D`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o/88769#88769) code. This question was updated with additional point sets, but when I tried to use my answer there, it failed. The OP used my answer and got really good results which made me realize something has changed between *Mathematica* versions **10.3.1** and **10.4**. I think I may have tracked the problem down to `DelaunayMesh`. To see what I mean, here are the `MeshRegion`s generated from the data obtained from the linked question using the same alpha parameter (**10.4** is on the right of the following images):

```
alphaShapes2D[points, 3.0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see it's more pronounced if we try to extract the region boundaries:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I tried to apply the code to the second data set provided (`points2`), *Mathematica* **10.3.1** returns the nice result shown in the linked question whereas, **10.4** fails to return any useful result. After spending some time debugging the only thing I could come up with is that `DelaunayMesh` is doing something different in both versions. For instance the number of mesh cells returned in both versions are different:

```
$Version
dd = DelaunayMesh[points];
MeshCellCount[dd, All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, as you can see from above, in **10.4** `DelaunayMesh` claims there's a degenerate polygon but we don't see this error in **10.3.1**. Can anyone reproduce this? Is this a change in algorithm in `DelaunayMesh`?

Comment: Same behavior for me (OS X, mma 10.3.1 / 10.4).

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises from the definition of `ellipsePoints` in the linked question, which maps over a range of angles `Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.02 Pi]`. Because the range includes both 0 and 2 Pi, there are duplicate points in the data. Simply changing to `Range[0.02 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.02 Pi]` makes the problem go away.

[image]

Comment: So, do you consider this new behavior a bug given that it worked fine pre **10.4**? Or is it the correct behavior? I personally think the algorithm should be smart enough to remove duplicate points.

Comment: @RunnyKine I'm not sure. The point is not perfectly duplicated due to roundoff errors. The triangulation works okay (it uses `TriangleDelaunay` from the `TriangleLink` package) and treats the points as distinct, but `MeshRegion` seems to treat them as equal. The inconsitency could be regarded as a bug.