# Possible Bug in ArrayMesh

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, mesh

**Bug introduced in V10.4 and fixed in 10.4.1**

---

Suppose we have the following array from which we intend to create an `ArrayMesh`:

```
arr = {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 
   0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}};
```

If we create the `ArrayMesh` and use one of the styling `Options` in this case `MeshCellStyle`, the color is not evenly applied:

```
ArrayMesh[arr, MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Yellow}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And as you manipulate this mesh object it flickers like crazy:

[image]

This does not happen if you use `HighlightMesh` to style it:

```
HighlightMesh[ArrayMesh[arr], {Style[2, Yellow]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics].

Can anyone reproduce this behavior. Note that `ArrayMesh` is new in **10.4**. I'm using **Windows 10 64bit**

Comment: Can reproduce this new kind of craziness in 10.4 on Win 10-64bit-NVIDIA gpu....

Comment: @PlatoManiac. I see what you did there :).

Comment: Same result on **Windows 7 32bit** using *V10.4*.

Comment: @BrettChampion, Is there a reason for removing the bug tag?

Comment: Just to let you know, I removed the version tag in accordance with the current [tag:bugs] policy [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info).

Comment: @MichaelE2. Thanks for the link, I must have missed the change in policy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an artifact in `Graphics3D` rendering ([Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)) which is generally difficult to avoid when using a depth buffer.

While `ArrayMesh` is new in 10.4, you would see similar behavior if you did copy and paste the result into an older version.

As a possible workaround, try

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
   RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]
```

Comment: @RunnyKine Good point, I've removed that suggestion, since it is not general enough.

Comment: Thanks. Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110598/regression-bug-in-delaunaymesh-from-10-3-1-to-10-4) ?