# How to compute the boundary of a group of ellipse efficiently?

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, regions, computational-geometry, intersection

#### Update1

[image]

I discovered that the bountary of a series of ellipses consists of the following three parts

> Part (I): the first ellipse's **effective** black-segment;
>
> Part (II): the **effective** envelope-points of the ellipes from the second to last second;
>
> Part (III): the last ellipse's **effective** red-segment;

Given that there are $n$ ellipses $E_1,E_2,\cdots,E_n$ on the plane.

- For the first ellipse $E_1$, the black segment that outside the ellipse $E_i(i=2,\cdots,n)$ is **effective**;
- For the envelope-point that on the ellipse $E_i(i=2,\cdots,n-1)$, the envelope-point $\theta_i$ that outsides the ellipse $E_j(j=1,\cdots,i-1,i+1,\cdots,n)$ is **effective**;
- For the last ellipse $E_n$, the red segment that outside the ellipse $E_i(i=1,\cdots,n-1)$ is **effective**;

#### Data

For a ellipse, which owns the following parametric formula

$\begin{cases}
 x=a \sin\theta+b \cos\theta +c  \\
 y=d \sin\theta +e \cos\theta +f  \\
\end{cases}$

where, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$

```
matThetaList =
 {{{{-0, -5, 0}, {-5.2203, 0, 1.7945}}, {2.4798, 5.7546}}, 
  {{{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.1765}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 2.3088}}, {3.1275, 6.2599}},
  {{{-1.8203, -4.7553, 0.2473}, {-5.6022 , 1.5451, 3.0486}}, {0.7316, 3.3481}},
  {{{-2.9427, -4.4550, 0.3147}, {-5.7755, 2.2700, 4.0578}}, {1.1944, 3.4426}}};
```

here, the variable `matThetaList` stores the ellipse $E_i$'s coefficient $\{\{a_i,b_i,c_i\},\{d_i,e_i,f_i\}\}$ and envelope-points $\theta_i^1,\theta_i^2$

Namely, `matThetaList=`
$\{ \\
       \{\{\{a_1,b_1,c_1\},\{d_1,e_1,f_1\}\},\{\theta_1^1,\theta_1^2\}\},\\
       \{\{\{a_2,b_2,c_2\},\{d_2,e_2,f_2\}\},\{\theta_2^1,\theta_2^2\}\},\\
      \cdots \\
       \}$

---

I have implemented this in [the Answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112212/how-to-solve-the-boundary-of-a-group-of-curve-segments-via-the-simple-rule/115324#115324), However, owing to the function `FindBoundary[]` will be called many times, the performance of my function is very **slow**.

[image]

So I would like to know:

- Is there other more better/efficient algorithm to solve the boundary of the Ellipses $E_1,\cdots,E_n$?.

#### Update2

---

For the general case(all the sections are the complete ellipse), [RunnyKine's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110236/is-there-a-numerical-method-built-in-to-calculate-the-boundary-of-a-set-of-graph/110608#110608) works well and it was very fast. However, when the section was a **partial** ellipse, that solution failed. Here is a partial ellipse case

```
(*data for ellipse segments*)
(*About ellipsePoints[], please see my answer below*)
ellipseMat = 
{{{0.,-5.,0.},{-5.22027,0.,0.294118}},
 {{-0.418837,-4.98459,0.228686},{-5.32183,0.392295,-0.033668}},  
 {{-0.858274,-4.93844,0.325822},{-5.41893,0.782172,-0.364501}},
 {{-1.32336,-4.86185,0.291034},{-5.51219,1.16723,-0.688098}},
 {{-1.82027,-4.75528,0.123195},{-5.60223,1.54509,-0.994631}},
 {{-2.35676,-4.6194,-0.179982},{-5.68973,1.91342,-1.27478}},
 {{-2.94275,-4.45503,-0.622558},{-5.77547,2.26995,-1.5198}},
 {{-3.59125,-4.2632,-1.2113},{-5.86038,2.61249,-1.72161}},
 {{-4.31974,-4.04509,-1.95715},{-5.94562,2.93893,-1.87293}},
 {{-5.15241,-3.80203,-2.8775},{-6.0327,3.24724,-1.96744}},
 {{-6.12372,-3.53553,-4.00001},{-6.12372,3.53553,-2.00001}}};

ellipseDomain = 
 {{2.38622,7.03856},{2.49067,6.93411},{2.57819,6.84659},{2.65607,6.76871},
  {2.72819,6.69659},{2.79696,6.62782},{2.86409,6.56069},{2.93095,6.49383},   
  {2.99873,6.42605},{3.06856,6.35622},{3.1416,6.28318}};

Graphics[Line[Append[#, First@#]] & /@ 
  MapThread[ellipsePoints, {ellipseMat, ellipseDomain}]]
```

[image]

When I sampling more sections($300$), I discovered that the boundary should be as below:

[image]

Comment: The method I showed, does it solve the problem for the static case?

Comment: @RunnyKine Although your method could trim the curve segment, it seemed that the **order** of the point-group was not correct.

Comment: I stated that in my answer, I also gave an alternative. Also you can use built-in functions to re-order them.

Comment: @bbgodfrey OK, I have added the data for ellipse segments:)

Comment: @bbgodfrey please see my answer below:)

Comment: Allows me to reproduce your curves.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I applied the **discrete** strategy(sampling $400$ points in a period $2\pi$) to calculate the boundary of ellipses $E_1,\cdots,E_n$. The algorithm mainly consists of four steps as follows :

- Using the ellipses $E_2,\cdots,E_n$ to trim the black segment of the first ellipse $E_1$;
- Using the ellipses $E_1,\cdots,E_{n-1}$ to trim the red segment of the last ellipse $E_n$;
- Delete the envelope-points of ellipses $E_2,\cdots,E_{n-1}$ that insides the all other ellipses(apart from itself).
- With the help of *built-in* `ListCurvePathPlot[]` to find the boundary

[image]

---

#### Implementation

```
FindBoundary[matThetaList_, firstBlackDom_, lastRedDom_] :=
 Module[{n, trimPolygon, envelope, validEnvelope, firstBlack, 
   lastRed, validFirstBlack, validLastRed, temp},
  n = Length[matThetaList];
  trimPolygon = 
   ellipsePoints[#, {0., 2 π}] & /@ matThetaList[[All, 1]];
  (*compute the coordinates of the ellipse*)
  envelope =
   Transpose[#1.{Sin[#2], Cos[#2], ConstantArray[1, Length@#2]}] & @@@
     matThetaList;
  (*compute the black segment of the first ellipse and red-segment of last ellipse*)
  firstBlack = ellipsePoints[matThetaList[[1, 1]], firstBlackDom];
  lastRed = ellipsePoints[matThetaList[[-1, 1]], lastRedDom];
  (*extract the effective envelope-point*)
  validEnvelope =
   Flatten[
    Pick[
     envelope,
     MapIndexed[validEnvelopeQ[trimPolygon, #1, First@#2] &, 
     envelope], True], 1];
  (*trim the in-effctive cut-points*)
  temp = firstBlack;
  Do[
   temp = Select[temp, ! inPolyQ[trimPolygon[[i]], #] &],
   {i, 2, n}
  ];
  validFirstBlack = temp;
  (*trim the in-effctive cutting-points*)
  temp = lastRed;
  Do[
   temp = Select[temp, ! inPolyQ[trimPolygon[[i]], #] &],
   {i, 1, n - 1}
  ];
  validLastRed = temp;
  (*visulize the boundary*)
  Show[
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[validEnvelope]}],
   ListCurvePathPlot[
    Join[validFirstBlack, validLastRed, validEnvelope], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic]
  ]
 ]
```

here, `firstBlackDom` and `lastRedDom` are the domain/interval list of the black segment of the first ellipse $E_1$ and red segment of last ellipse $E_n$, respectively.

#### Auxiliary function

```
ellipsePoints[mat_, dom : {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}] := 
  mat.{Sin[#], Cos[#], 1} & /@ Range[a, b, Pi/200.0]
ellipsePoints[mat_, dom : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}] := 
  mat.{Sin[#], Cos[#], 1} & /@
   Join @@ (Range[#[[1]], #[[2]], Pi/200.0] & /@ dom)

validEnvelopeQ[trimPolygon_, pt : {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}, idx_] :=
 Module[{trimPoly},
  trimPoly = Delete[trimPolygon, idx];
  And @@ (! inPolyQ[#, pt] & /@ trimPoly)
 ]
validEnvelopeQ[trimPolygon_, pts : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, idx_] := 
  validEnvelopeQ[trimPolygon, #, idx] & /@ pts

inPolyQ1 = Compile[{{poly, _Real, 2}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},
   Block[{Xi, Yi, Xip1, Yip1, u, v, w},
    {Xi, Yi} = Transpose@poly;
    Xip1 = RotateLeft@Xi;
    Yip1 = RotateLeft@Yi;
    u = UnitStep[y - Yi];
    v = RotateLeft@u;
    w = UnitStep[-((Xip1 - Xi) (y - Yi) - (x - Xi) (Yip1 - Yi))];
    Total[(u (1 - v) (1 - w) - (1 - u) v w)] != 0]
   ];

 inPolyQ[poly_, pt : {x_, y_}] := inPolyQ1[poly, x, y]
```

Here, the `inPolyQ[]` came from Simon Woods's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon/9414#9414)

#### TEST

```
matThetaList =
  {{{{-0, -5, 0}, {-5.2203, 0, 1.7945}}, {2.4798, 5.7546}}, 
   {{{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.1765}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 2.3088}}, {3.1275, 6.2599}},
   {{{-1.8203, -4.7553, 0.2473}, {-5.6022 , 1.5451, 3.0486}}, {0.7316,3.3481}},
   {{{-2.9427, -4.4550, 0.3147}, {-5.7755, 2.2700, 4.0578}}, {1.1944, 3.4426}}};

firstBlackDom = {{5.7546, 2 π}, {0, 2.4798}};
lastRedDom = {{3.4426, 2 π}, {0, 1.1944}};

FindBoundary[matThetaList, firstBlackDom, lastRedDom]
```

[image]

Another test

```
matThetaList2 =
{{{{0., -5., 0.}, {-5.22027, 0., 1.79454}}, {1.41134, 5.00261}}, 
 {{{-0.418837, -4.98459, 0.375413}, {-5.32183, 0.392295, 1.83067}}, {1.35018, 5.13206}}, 
 {{{-0.858274, -4.93844, 0.679152}, {-5.41893, 0.782172, 1.86633}}, {1.22638, 5.26839}}, 
 {{{-1.32336, -4.86185, 0.914622}, {-5.51219, 1.16723, 1.90933}}, {1.00134, 5.41161}}, 
 {{{-1.82027, -4.75528, 1.08554}, {-5.60223, 1.54509, 1.96716}}, {0.678781, 5.56818}}, 
 {{{-2.35676, -4.6194, 1.19594}, {-5.68973, 1.91342, 2.047}}, {0.293121, 2.34024, 2.95781, 5.76617}}, 
 {{{-2.94275, -4.45503, 1.25017}, {-5.77547, 2.26995, 2.15563}}, {2.14864, 3.23955}},
 {{{-3.59125, -4.2632, 1.25283}, {-5.86038, 2.61249, 2.29949}}, {2.0766, 3.38628}}, 
 {{{-4.31974, -4.04509, 1.20875}, {-5.94562, 2.93893, 2.48455}}, {2.04293, 3.47937}}, 
 {{{-5.15241, -3.80203, 1.12285}, {-6.0327, 3.24724, 2.71637}}, {2.02746, 3.54081}}, 
 {{{-6.12372, -3.53553, 0.999988}, {-6.12372, 3.53553, 2.99999}}, {2.02227, 3.58014}}};

FindBoundary[
  matThetaList2, {{0, 1.411339}, {5.00261, 2 π}}, 
                 {{3.580142, 2 π}, {0, 2.022272}}]
```

[image]

---

Here is two screenshots that applied my method.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Solution for Update1**

The ellipses described by `matThetaList` can be plotted by

```
Show[ParametricPlot[#[[1]].{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ matThetaList, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

To describe each of these four curves as an `ImplicitRegion`, first eliminate `θ` from the parametric equations given in the question,

```
h = Total[#^2 & /@ ({Sin[θ], Cos[θ]} /. Solve[{x - c == a Sin[θ] + b Cos[θ], 
    y - f == d Sin[θ] + e Cos[θ]}, {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}] // Flatten)]
(* (c d - a f - d x + a y)^2/(b d - a e)^2 + 
   (-c e + b f + e x - b y)^2/(b d - a e)^2 *)
```

then use `h < 1` to define each `ImplicitRegion`, combine the four into a single region with `RegionUnion`, improve resolution with `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`, and plot with `RegionPlot`.

```
RegionPlot[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[ImplicitRegion[
    (h /. Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f} -> Flatten@#[[1]]]) < 1, {x, y}] & /@ 
    matThetaList], MaxCellMeasure -> .25], PlotStyle -> White]
```

[image]

which is the desired envelope of the four ellipses.  The computation takes less than two seconds on my PC.

In the same way, the curve for `matThetaList2`, added in the OP's answer, can be computed quite accurately in three seconds.

[image]

**Solution for Update2**

The more difficult problem of finding the envelop of several truncated ellipses is treated similarly, the difference being that each `ImplicitRegion` is to be truncated.  To do so, first compute the lines that truncate each ellipse.  This is accomplished, first, by determining the points on the ellipses where truncation occurs, and next determining the line that connects these two points.

```
lims = Simplify[#[[1, 2]] + (#[[2, 2]] - #[[1, 2]])/(#[[2, 1]] - #[[1, 1]]) 
    (x - #[[1, 1]])] & /@  
    (# & /@ MapThread[{#1.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1} /. θ -> #2[[1]], #1.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1} /. 
    θ -> #2[[2]]} &, {ellipseMat, ellipseDomain}])
(* {-3.28469 + 1.06453*10^-6 x, -3.26025 - 0.0787005 x, -3.27957 - 0.158383 x, ... *)
```

Finally, this line is used in a second condition of `ImplicitRegion`.

```
RegionPlot[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[MapThread[ImplicitRegion[
    (y > #2) && ((h /. Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f} -> Flatten@#1]) < 1), {x, y}] &, 
    {ellipseMat, lims}]], MaxCellMeasure -> .25], PlotStyle -> White]
```

[image]

as desired.  This computation requires just under four seconds on my PC, measured with `AbsoluteTiming`.  If, as seems likely, timing scales linearly with the number of ellipses, the 200-ellipse computation mentioned in the question would take about 70 seconds.

**Addendum**

To verify this timing estimate, and also to verify that no catastrophe occurs as the number of ellipses is increased, I generated 101 truncated ellipses by interpolation from the eleven ellipses given in the question.

```
interpDomain = Interpolation[#] & /@ Transpose[ellipseDomain];
tableDomain = Table[Through[interpDomain[i]], {i, 1, 11, 1/10}];
interpMat = Interpolation[#] & /@ Transpose[Flatten[#] & /@ ellipseMat];
tableMat = Table[Partition[Through[interpMat[i]], 3], {i, 1, 11, 1/10}];
```

Here is a plot of the truncated ellipses in `Red` and their truncating lines in `Black`.

[image]

Then, applying the same code used above provides the envelope.

[image]

in just under fifty seconds, again measuring runtime with `AbsoluteTiming`.  My Windows PC has four processors, each with two threads.  Interestingly, the computation used 50% or more of the total CPU capacity, indicating very effective parallelization for these geometric functions.  A 301 ellipse calculation produced essentially the save envelope curve, but running just over three times as long.  Strangely, a 201 ellipse calculation produced the same envelope curve, but with a small glitch in one location.  I have not pursued why.

Comment: In my work, I need to compute the boundary/envelope many times($200$), so the performance of the function `FindBoundary[]` is very important. Although RunnyKine's [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110236/is-there-a-numerical-method-built-in-to-calculate-the-boundary-of-a-set-of-graph/110608#110608) is very fast, it cannot deal with the ellipse segment. So in my answer, I applied the **discrete strategy** and **trimed** the line segment via polygon. Unfortunately, it is not fast. So I asked this question to seek the more efficient algorithm/soluton.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG  Thanks for this information.  I know how to generalize the solution above, but I do not know how fast it will be.

Comment: I would like to know how to **generalize** your solution to partial ellipse segment. Maybe you could update that method to your answer:) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG  That is what I have in mind, and I hope to do today.  By the way, do analytical expressions exist for your truncated ellipse parameters?  Are the truncation points symmetric about the rotated major axes?  Do all the truncated ellipses enclose the origin (or, at any rate, some common point)?  Finally, are you ultimately seeking a boundary curve for an infinite number of truncated ellipses?

Comment: (1)The analytical @bbgodfrey [expressions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed7jk.png) indeed exist for the truncted ellipse, that is, $\theta \in [\theta_{\min},\theta_{\max}]$ About the last point, I would like to use the **discrete** method(sample a series of sections)seek the boundary/envelope of the infinite number of truncated/complete ellipses section.

Comment: In fact, the truncated/complete ellipse came from the [intersection-curve](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jrGIv.png) of a cylinder and a plane $\Omega$. Here, the plane $\Omega$ is perpendicular to the palne $y_To_Tz_T$, please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eGxqi.png). In additon, the cylinder was modelled in its coordinate system $o_T-x_Ty_Tz_T$, that is $$\begin{cases}x=R\cos\theta\\y=R\sin\theta\\z=l\end{cases}$$and the plane $\Omega$ has a analytical equation $z_w=z_{\Omega}$ in its coordinate system $o_w-x_wy_wz_w$ . The two  coordinate systems own a **transformation matrix** $M_{T->w}$

Comment: Here is a simple [schematic diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cuXdX.png)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG  Because you "would like to use the discrete method(sample a series of sections)", I have not given much thought to obtaining a solution in the limit of an infinite number of ellipses.  I would guess that doing so is feasible for complete ellipses, but perhaps not for truncated ellipses, because they lead to discontinuous derivatives of the curves.  In any case, 100 or more truncated ellipses gives good results for boundary curves.

Comment: Thanks, @bbgodfrey, so I applied other method in my [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112212/how-to-compute-the-boundary-of-a-group-of-ellipse-efficiently/115324#115324) to calculate the boundary/envelope. About explanation, please see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112212/how-to-compute-the-boundary-of-a-group-of-ellipse-efficiently)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG  I am glad that you found my answer useful.  Certainly, I learned a lot developing it.  Thank you for the bounty.

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7NJrO.png) is a solution that applying my theory explained in **Update1**. Namely, the last envelope consists of three parts. (1) the valid/effective **black segment** of the first truncated ellipse (2)the valid/effective **red segment** of the last truncated ellipse (3)the **end-point** and **envelope-point** of the middle truncated ellipse

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Very nice, indeed (+1).  I imagine that, once you have these points, you could use the corresponding ellipse segments to provide a smoother envelope without much difficulty.  By the way, in your question you describe your approach as slow.  Just how slow is it?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe @bbgodfrey the `FindBoundary[]` was fast when it was called just $1$ time, but in my work, I need to called it many times, ($200$ or more), in this condition, the performance of `FindBoundary[]` became critical/key. Here is [benchmark](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C1KC7.png). So I asked this question to seek **more efficient** implementation of my **discovery** about the **envelope composition**.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG  I see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an approach that seems to work for the cases presented, I think it may be general if you're only dealing with two curves. For more than two curves, you'll just need to extend the approach a little.

```
getSurf[pt1_, pt2_] := 
 Module[{gr1 = Graphics[Line[pt1 ~ Join ~ {pt1[[1]]}]], 
   gr2 = Graphics[Line[pt2 ~ Join ~ {pt2[[1]]}]], reg},
  reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ {gr1, gr2};
  DeleteCases[MeshCoordinates@RegionUnion@reg, 
        Alternatives @@ (MeshCoordinates@RegionIntersection@reg)]]
```

The function just takes the points of the two curves and returns the points of the trimmed boundary. 
For the first case:

```
GraphicsRow[ListPlot[getSurf[pts1, pts2], AspectRatio -> 1, Joined -> #] & /@ 
           {False, True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the second case:

```
getSurf[pts3, pts4] // ListPlot[#, AspectRatio -> 1] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]